# Python re module

Tags: python, regex, excel, python-3.x

I have to fill excel spreadsheet with prices in column B

[image: Sample]

Since price is the same for article starting "0288" and four numbers after dash does not mean anything so I want to give them one value like this:

```
article_0288 = re.compile('0288-(.{4})$')
```

but when I try to test it, values do not match:

```
test = "0288-4000"
article_0288 == test

False
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you at least come up with a better title? Your current one tells us nothing about your actual question.

Comment: `article_0288` is a compiled regular expression object. It will only test equal with another regular expression object with the same value. You should really read the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and the [Python regex HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) before attempting to use the module.

Answer (score 0):

once you create the regex object with `re.compile()` you need to use it like this:

```
matches=article_0288.match(test)
```

this will return a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match) that you can get the matches from using `group()` like this:

```
print matches.group(0)
```

you can use the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) page for `group()` to help you understand it a little better